# Identify same successively values in a vector in R

Tags: r

I'm new here and not really a pro in R. Hope you guys can help me out.

I've a vector *ls* and want to identify at least three same successively values in there.

Example:

```
ls <- c(1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
```

Now I want to identify the position in *ls*, where the **minimum** of three successively -1's does **start**. Here the output (the positions) would be :

```
[1]  4  10
```

Does any of you have an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle`

```
 r <- rle(ls)
 (cumsum(r$lengths)-r$lengths+1)[r$value==-1 & r$length>=3]
 #> [1]  4 10
```

The cummulative sum of run-lengths gives the endpoints of runs. Subtracting the lengths gives to position immediately before they start, so add one back. Subset the result for places where the value is -1 and the run-length is at least 3.